# find closed contours in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect all the closed contours in image. So I am using opencv python library  for contours detection.

But this function returns multiple open contours (But actually it is a closed contour). So please give some solution to extract contours as closed contour.

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the contour is convex or not. You can check this with the function [cv2.isContourConvex(cnt)](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.isContourConvex). The function just returns `True` or `False`.

You could then just run a loop through all your contours i.e:

```
closed_contours = []

for cnt in contours:
   if cv2.isContourConvex(cnt) == True:
      closed_contours.append(cnt)
   else:
      pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cv2.contourArea()

```
closed_contours = []

for i in range(len(contours)):
    if cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > cv2.arcLength(contours[i], True):
        closed_contours.append(contours[i])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).